# two finger scroll issues: erratic selecting and app switching -Macbook pro 8,1

Tags: 13.04, touchpad, macbook, multi-touch, synaptics

I've got ubuntu 13.04 on a Macbook pro 8,1

I'm having issues with two fingered scrolling,

1:
I can't select multiple items from a long list,
because when I touch my fingers on the pad to scroll through the list, it selects as if I was doing a 1 one fingered tap.

2:
Having two fingers on the pad sometimes opens the switcher and causes rapid cycling through the apps.

Here are my touch pad settings from synclient -l

Parameter settings:

```
LeftEdge                = -3611
RightEdge               = 4246
TopEdge                 = 517
BottomEdge              = 6108
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
FingerPress             = 257
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 511
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
FastTaps                = 0
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 283
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = -232
HorizScrollDelta        = -232
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0172176
TrackstickSpeed         = 40
EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 929
EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
TouchpadOff             = 0
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 3
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 37
VertHysteresis          = 26
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 0
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 0
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

and from dconf
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad

```
disable-while-typing 1
horiz-scroll-enabled 1
left-handed          mouse
motion-acceleration  3
motion-threshold     8
natural-scroll       1
scroll-method        two-finger-scrolling
tap-to-click         1
touchpad-enabled     1
```

any suggestions?

thanks mat

Answer (score 0):

This is three finger tap followed by hold to switch between app windows. The explanation here. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

You can disable it by following instruction in this link, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/TouchpadSupport , but I think it will be better to keep the setting as default, just change in the system setting >> touchpad.